Displaying Formula field on vf page
I am trying to display field value of Product Type on Vf page.
The problem is the product type value is not displaying on vf page.
Note: I have tried inputfield, outputfield, outputtext tags but same result no change.
Please refer the code and screenshot

<apex:outputPanel id="complaintQuestions">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Questions" id="complaintQs" columns="1" rendered="{!nonMigratedFlagChecked}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.NonMigratedPolicyNumber__c}" required="true" style="width: 300px" />
        
        <!-- Product Name Lookup Field -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.ProductName__c}" id="productName" onchange="updateProductType();"/>
        
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.ExternalTrustee__c}" style="width: 300px"/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.NonMigratedClaimRef__c}" style="width: 300px"/>
        
        <!-- Output Text for Product Type -->
        <apex:outputText value="{!ProductType}" label="Product Type" style="width: 300px" id="productType"/>
        
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Catastrophe_Event__c}" id="catastropheEvent" onclick="lineOfBusiness();"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Catastrophe_Event_Details__c}" id="catastropheEventDetail" style="width: 300px"/>
        
        <!-- Action Function to Recalculate Product Type -->
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:actionFunction name="updateProductType" action="{!fetchProductType}" rerender="productType"/>
</apex:outputPanel>

public void fetchProductType() {
    if (theCase.ProductName__c != null){
        Product_Directory__c product =[SELECT Product_Type__c FROM Product_Directory__c Where Product_Name__c =: the Case.ProductName__c LIMIT 1];
        ProductType = product.Product_Type__c;
    } else {
        ProductType = null;
    }
}


Formula fields are a database feature rather than a UI feature.
That means that you're going to need to get the data from your VF page back into your controller (or extension) where you can call Formula.recalculateFormulas(). This works even with cross-object formulas (only tested a formula field that references a field on a parent record. Haven't tested 2+ levels of parent traversal)1.
If you want to have that formula (re)calculate without pressing the "submit" button, your only choice is to use something like an <apex:actionFunction> that you can then use in the onChange attribute in the relevant <apex:inputField> tag(s). The <apex:actionFunction> has a rerender attribute that you can use to re-render something like an <apex:outputPanel>.
In general, the thing you're looking for is a "partial page refresh".
1: This only appears to work if you specify the Id field. So if you have a formula field on Account to pull in the Record Type Name...
-- Using new Account(RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Some Rec Type').getRecordTypeId()) will populate the record type name formula field when you call Formula.recalculateFormulas(new List<Account>{ inMemoryAccount });
-- Using new Account(RecordType = new RecordType(Name = 'Some Rec Type')) will not populate the record type name formula field
Still not sure if it works for multiple levels of parent references, and the parent record needs to be inserted before this will work.


Hi @Derek, my problem is why the product type field is not displaying any value, and I want to display it's value at every point of time while I am working with another fields on the vf Page. If see the vf Page image see the difference between the product type field layout and other fields layout

@PavanKumarHechu My answer goes over what you would need to do. Again, formula fields are something that happens in the database, behind the scenes. Salesforce has given us the ability to recalculate formulas in Apex, so that's your only option.

even I used the recalculate formulas it was not working.              Lets forget about formula field Could you help me with how can I display the selected records one of the field value based on the lookup selection. Here I just want to display the value with label, like label 'Product Type' one of the field value of the selected record. On vf page. It should impact anything while submitting, use just for displaying purpose.

I just updated my codes please check
